# Componete pronto

Tags: primefaces, java-ee, bootstrap-3

Bom dia. Pessoal alguem sabe me dizer se existe algum outro componente sem ser o editor do primefaces,  na qual tem as seguintes propriedades também: font,tamanho da font, centralizar, alinhar esquerda, alinhar direita...etc.

Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu uso o [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), acho ele muito bom! Você consegue customizar do jeito que quer.

Comment: Entendi.. como faço para colocar no meu codigo?